# How to trim the mesh

Tags: modifiers

I have the stars above and below half circle. I want to trim the half circle shape as mark in red color. I have used the boolean modifier but its not working. I have remove all doubles and flip normal yet no result. Any help
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Apply** **Rotation** and **Scale** to both the Star and Circle object.

[image]

[image]

Then try using the Boolean modifier again.